# Add data to DataTable

Tags: c#, .net-datatable

I created a class to operate with concrete table and I want to generalize this code to develop more universal class.

Here is one method of this class:

```
public void FillColumns(DataTable table, OracleDataReader reader)
{
  if (reader != null)
    if (reader.HasRows)
    {
      table.Rows.Clear();
      while (reader.Read()) table.Rows.Add
          (
            reader["ColumnName1"],
            reader["ColumnName2"],
            reader["ColumnName3"],
            reader["ColumnName4"]
          );
    }
}
```

How can I refactor this concrete method, to make concrete column names as input parameters (even independing of number of columns)?

Comment: Yes, I'm talking about only one method which I want to refactor.

Comment: Does it has to be a DataTable? Comparing with POCOs, DataTable is a bit slower.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## params (version 1)

You can use the same *trick* the `Rows.Add` method uses namely the [`params`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5zay9db.aspx) keyword

> By using the params keyword, you can specify a method parameter that takes a variable number of arguments.

and pass columns names as the last parameters. Then you read the values form the reader with some LINQ and turn it into an array because it's just that, an array (but one that is created dynamically if each value is passed separately). Besides you don't need two `if`s, use the and `&&` operator instead.

```
public void FillColumns(
    DataTable table, 
    OracleDataReader  reader, 
    params string[] columnNames)
{
    if (reader != null && reader.HasRows)
    {
        table.Rows.Clear();
        while (reader.Read()) 
        {
            table.Rows.Add(columnNames.Select(name => reader[name]).ToArray());
        }
    }
}
```

Example call:

```
.FillColumns(table, reader, "Column1", "Column2");
```

---

## table.Columns (version 2)

the second approach would be to read the column names from the data table

```
public void FillColumns(DataTable table, OracleDataReader reader)
{
    if (reader != null && reader.HasRows)
    {
        table.Rows.Clear();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            table.Rows.Add(
                table
                .Columns
                .Cast<DataColumn>()
                .Select(column => reader[column.ColumnName])
                .ToArray());
        }
    }
}
```

---

## table.Load (version 3)

and the third to just load the datatable from the reader:

```
public void FillColumns(DataTable table, OracleDataReader reader)
{
    if (reader != null && reader.HasRows)
    {
        table.Rows.Clear();
        table.Load(reader);        
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you!  I'll try to understand your examples of code ...

Comment: The reason I complicated construction of  if (reader != null && reader.HasRows)   I thought that reader.HasRows throws the exception if object is null

Comment: @GordonFreeman I guess your background is VB? Because there the_old_ And operator works that way. I think the new one is AndAlso and behaves like the C# &&.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Your first variant is most suitable for me.

Comment: (my background is Delphi)